# Error Wamp : the procedure entry point isalpha could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\pcre.dll

Tags: php, apache, dll, wampserver

I'm installing wampserver3.0.6_x64_apache2.4.23_mysql5.7.14_php5.6.25-7.0.10 but i have some library's problem (api-ms-win-crt-*) that i solved after downloading it on (https://www.dll-files.com/).

But i have another problem for which i don't find any solution after many researchs. when i'm starting Wamp i have this message :

**"The procedure entry point isalpha could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\pcre.dll"**

**Other Information**

- OS Version : Windows 8.1 64- bit.
- PHP Version : 5.6.25
- MS Visual C++ Version : MS Redistribuable 2012 (x64)

Thanks in advance for your help !

**PS** : Sorry for my english i'm a french man:)

Comment: Sigh... when will MS-Windows _finally_ get a working software management system as it is known, proven and used under Linux where that simply is resolved automatically?

Comment: @arkascha you don't know any solution for windows?

Comment: That was a general remark about issues arising with software installations in MS-Windows systems, nothing specific for your question. Still, you suffer from exactly that lack of a software management.

Comment: The issue at hand _obviously_ is that you have software packages (libraries) that do not match. Most likely wrong versions or wrong build types. Nothing we can say in this. you downloaded something from somewhere in some version. And, surprise, surprise, things do not match. Sorry, but nothing we can help with. You will have to try to find a matching version. A search for a needle in a haystack, I know.

Comment: ok thank you so much for your response